# A simple Calculator DSL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dsl

I'm implementing a Calculator DSL in Ruby. The code is given below. It gives me an error stating that '+' in total = total + number is not defined. What could be the error? Also, could there be any problem in the initialize function that is causing it?

```
class Calculator 
attr_accessor :total

def initialize(&block)
    self.total = 0
    instance_eval(&block)
    return total
end

def add(number)
     total = total + number
end

def subtract(number)
    total -= number
end

def multiply(number)
    total *= number
end

def divide(number)
    total /= number
end
end

h = Calculator.new do
  add 3
  add 5
end
```

The error message is -

```
  calculator_dsl.rb:10:in `add': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from calculator_dsl.rb:27:in `block in <main>'
from calculator_dsl.rb:5:in `instance_eval'
from calculator_dsl.rb:5:in `initialize'
from calculator_dsl.rb:26:in `new'
from calculator_dsl.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are getting as well

Comment: yup @rkon i posted it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: name clash (local variable vs method)

Long answer:

```
def add(number)
  puts defined?(total)
  total = (puts defined?(total); total + number)
end
```

This code outputs

```
method
local-variable
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Right before this line

```
 total = total + number
```

a new local variable `total` is created which shadows the method from outer scope. It is also set to `nil` which explains the error you're getting.

To avoid creation of new local var, use `self`

```
 self.total = total + number
 # or
 self.total += number
```

Comment: do you know how i can overcome that? My main aim is to use total as sort of a global variable and then use 'add 3' followed by 'add 5' to give me 8 as the answer.